# Windows Server - Active Directory users: Clear Caches

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, cache, users

On Windows Server 2008/2003, users are logging in via Active Directory. So I believe that all of them have cached local settings when they log in the first time and onwards.

How/Where do you clear this cache?

Thanks

Comment: When you say *"cached local settings"*, do you mean the user profiles stored locally to the clients, or the cached credentials which allow offline logon?

Comment: Are you referring to their user profile, which contains application settings, etc. or are you referring to their cached credentials, which allow them to log onto their computer with their domain user account even when they're disconnected from the domain?

Comment: Hi all. I refer to the user profile, which contains application settings

Comment: OK, so you want to know how to delete/reset a user profile on a computer?  (just verifying, but jscott or joe or google can easily answer this one)

Comment: @TheCleaner - No, I do not want to delete a user profile, I just want to clear/access its user cache

Comment: You're not making sense. You don't want to delete the user profile you want to clear the user cache? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: The first time a user logs onto the server, somewhere on the server there rests cached settings from - applications, user settings such as appearance settings etc. Are you telling me that clearing a user's cached settings and deleting the user is the same thing?

Comment: A "user profile" and a "user account" are 2 different things...if that's where your confusion lies.

Comment: The settings you're referring to are part of the user profile. So you DO want to delete the user profile. You do that from System Properties>Advanced properties tab>User Profiles section>Settings button>Select the user profile you want to delete>Click Delete button. - Also, it seems that you're confusing the user profile with the user account. Deleting the user profile DOES NOT delete the user account.

Comment: @joeqwerty...Thank you for clearing that vou for me. So deleting the user profile will clear all its preferences, but keeps the user account right?